# Formula: Excel Find and Replace All full stops before specified characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, find-and-replace, wildcards

I have a column of research data I wanted to clean.

As users have not followed instructions, there are unnecessary full stops in the sentences. I need to remove all full stops that are before a space and lowercase letter.
For example:

```
This will help. to do that task. I'm sure. to complete it.
```

I want to remove all the '.' before the 'to'. I'll need to do it with various other sentences with different content.

How can it be done with a formula? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using VBA:

- Open the Visual Basic IDE using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Insert a new public module using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>
- Paste the following code into the module:

  ```
  Function StripPeriods(strArg As String) As String
      Dim intPos As Integer
      Dim intCha As Integer
      intPos = InStr(1, strArg, ". ")
      If intPos > 0 And intPos + 2 < Len(strArg) Then
          intCha = Asc(Mid(strArg, intPos + 2, 1))
          If intCha > 96 And intCha < 123 Then
              StripPeriods = Left(strArg, intPos - 1) & StripPeriods(Mid(strArg, intPos + 1))
          Else
              StripPeriods = Left(strArg, intPos) & StripPeriods(Mid(strArg, intPos + 1))
          End If
      Else
          StripPeriods = strArg
      End If
  End Function
  ```
- In a new column or worksheet, call the above function in a formula referencing the target cells, e.g.:

  ```
  =StripPeriods(A1)
  ```
- Select & copy the results of the formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
- Paste Special the results as Values over the original cells (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple find & replace looking for a “ . “ ie a full stop with a space each side and replace with just a space. You may find that you should find & replace any double spaces first...

Edit : added after info in comment:
Then you could search for ". t" and replace with " t" which should capture most of them...

Comment: Thank you, but I'm sorry I added an extra space. I couldn't put the real data is here so I had to make it up.

Comment: I have different sets of sentences, not all have a " .t". It's different in each sentence. Any ideas?